# Как растянуть фон?

Tags: html, css

Как растянуть фон на весь экран? 
Вот так не работает:

```
<body background="fon.jpg"  width="100" height="100">
```

Картинка есть, но их несколько штук.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: размеры `width/height` устанавливаются относительно родительского блока.

Answer (score 4):

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=1024&d=identicon&r=PG) center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=1024&d=identicon&r=PG) center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!! Но относится у меня к <body>.

Comment: @Zero, можно и для body.

Answer (score 2):

```
<body style="background: url('img1.jpg') no-repeat fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;">
```

Comment: `cover` сохраняет пропорции.

Comment: `cover` - заполняет ввесь фон картинкой.

Comment: Да. Но с сохранением пропорций. А то, что не поместится, просто исчезает. Растягивания картинки нет (хотя увеличение может быть) - я это имел в виду.

Comment: я понял Вас, просто дописал что он еще и заполняет фон, то есть как человеку нужно было на ввесь экран поставить фон.